# Spread values across rows Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spread

I have two tables (one for purchase order and the other for the invoice) and I want to distribute the quantity from the invoice table to the purchase order invoice quantity column but I want to match the exact quantity from the purchase order quantity.

Here is how the table looks now

[image: Here is how the table looks now]

And this is how I want it to look:

[image]

How do I manage to do that? Thanks!

Here is the excel attachment file:
[Book1.xlsx](http://cloud.aplicabil.ro/index.php/s/8SGuTjFUXfQ1zD6)

Update:
Is it possible to do that for multiple codes?

[image]

Comment: Changing the conditions of a question sufficiently that valid answers are no longer valid is considered bad forum etiquette. Close this question off and start a new one if you have new requirements. See [Etiquette for Russian Doll Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions).

Answer (score 1):

With **Invoice Quantity** in the E2 cell and and **Qty** in the M2 cell, put this formula into E3,

```
=MAX(MIN(M$3-SUM(E$2:E2), D3), 0)
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: max_min_qty]

Comment: Wow! You worth millions! Would it be possible to do that for multiple codes like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/fI46x.jpg

Comment: Yes it would. Use the [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) for a one column conditional match. There are numerous examples on this site; I've written dozens myself.

Comment: I see. Could you give me a little example related to this situation? I'm kinda new to the aggregate function.

Comment: Actually, I may have spoken prematurely. I completed the formula on your sample worksheet using nothing more complicated than the [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) and [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B)  functions inside the formula provided above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Consolidate function to do so.

1. Click a cell where you want to locate the result in your current worksheet.
2. Go to click `Data > Consolidate`

[image: doc-combine-sum3]

3. In the `Consolidate dialog box`:

   (1.) Select `Sum` from Function drop down list;

   (2.) Click [image: doc-combine-sum5] button to select the range that you want to consolidate, and then click `Add` button to add the reference to All references list box;

   (3.) Check `Top row` and `Left column` from Use labels in option.

[image: doc-combine-sum4]

4. After finishing the settings, click `OK`, and the duplicates are combined and summed.

[image: doc-combine-sum6]

**Note:** If the range do not have the header row, you need uncheck Top row from the Use labels in option.

***Reference***: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1268-excel-combine-duplicate-rows-and-sum.html

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to consolidate multiple rows into one. I want exactly the opposite. Spread the sum to multiple rows.

Comment: It does the same thing .. I'll edit my answer. (and who -1 my answer?)