# Spread values across rows based on codes

Tags: excel

I have two tables (1.Purchase order and 2.The invoice) and I want to spread the quantity from the invoice table to the purchase order invoice quantity column by code but I want to match the exact quantity from the purchase order quantity.

Here is how the table looks now:

**Purchase order** table *and* **Invoice** table
[image]

And this is how i want it to look:

[image]

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851589/spread-values-across-rows-excel) post a formula was suggested

```
=MAX(MIN(M$2-SUM(E$1:E1), D2), 0)
```

which I customized to use vlookup so it can match the code,

```
=MAX(MIN(VLOOKUP(A2,J:M,4,FALSE)-SUM(E$1:E1), D2), 0)
```

but that doesn't work.

@Jeeped suggested to use `AGGREGATE` function for a one column conditional match, but can anyone give me an example related to this situation?

Here is the sample [Excel  file](http://cloud.aplicabil.ro/index.php/s/6HfAa3rgB0xRpmf)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In E2 as,

```
=MAX(MIN(VLOOKUP(A2, J:N, 4, FALSE)-SUMIFS(E$1:E1, A$1:A1, A2), D2), 0)
```

What happened to row 1?

Comment: Good to see that you gave it a try and glad to help out.